# minimum changes required to make string continuous x no. of A and then after (n-x) no.s of B

Tags: java, java-8

I am stuck in one of the problem related string in Java. My logic has worked well for some test cases, but not for all test cases. Please suggest me the actual logic of the following question::

I am given a string s of n character, comprising only of A's and B's . I can choose any index i and change s(i) to either A or B. Find the minimum no. Of changes that you must make to string S such that the resultant string is of format : AAAAA.....BBBBB. In other words, my task is to determine minimum no. of changes such that string s has x no. of A's in the beginning, followed by the remaining (n-x) no. of B's.

Sample Input is as below
4
3
AAB
5
AABAA
1
B
4
BABA

First line: A single integer  denoting the number of test cases
For each test case:
First line contains a single integer  denoting the size of the string
Second line contains string

My code is as below

```
import java.util.*;
class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        TestClass t = new TestClass();
        int test_case = s.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < test_case; i++){
            int len = s.nextInt();
            String none = s.nextLine();
            String str = s.nextLine();
            int cnta = t.count_ab(str,'A');
            int cntb = t.count_ab(str,'B');
            char c1 = '1';
            if(cnta > cntb){
                c1 = 'A';
            }
            else{
                c1 = 'B';
            }
            int count = 0;
            int c1_count = 0;
            int c2_count = 0;
            if(str.length() > 1){
                String rev = "";
                c1_count = t.cnt_init_a(str, 'A');
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
                rev = sb.reverse().toString();
                c2_count = t.cnt_init_a(rev, 'B');
                int rem_len = str.length() - c2_count;
                for(int h = c1_count; h < rem_len; h++){
                    if(Character.compare(str.charAt(h), c1) != 0){
                        count = count + 1;
                    }
                }

            }
            System.out.println(count);
        }
    }

    public int cnt_init_a(String str, char c){
        int cnt = 0;
        for(int l = 0; l < str.length(); l++){
            if(Character.compare(str.charAt(l), c) == 0){
                cnt = cnt + 1;
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        }
        return cnt;
    }

    public int count_ab(String str, char c){
        int cnt = 0;
        for(int g = 0; g < str.length(); g++){
            if(Character.compare(str.charAt(g), c) == 0){
                cnt = cnt + 1;
            }
        }
        return cnt;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic fails for e.g. `"BAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBB"` and `"AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBA"`.

You should start by ignoring all leading A's and all trailing B's, since they should never be changed.

`"BAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBB"` -> `"BAAAAAAAAAA"` (removed trailing B's)
`"AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBA"` -> `"BBBBBBBBBBA"` (removed leading A's)

Then change either the leading B's to A's, or the trailing A's to B's, whichever is shorter.

Then repeat the process.